# Google Cloud warnings that conflict each other

Tags: command-line, devops, gcloud, gcloud-compute

### TLDR in brief

gcloud compute instance to have hard disk size under 200Gb get warning but when set to 200Gb will get another warning.

### in details

When we *create instance template*, as command 01 below, we have this warning if setting hard disk size 10Gb

> WARNING: You have selected a disk size of under [200GB]. This may result in poor I/O performance. For more information, see: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#performance

Though when we do set it to 200Gb, we get this warning when **creating instance from that template**

> WARNING: Some requests generated warnings:
>     Disk size: '200 GB' is larger than image size: '10 GB'. You might need to resize the root repartition manually if the operating system does not support automatic resizing. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#repartitionrootpd for details.

So why you gcloud warn us from the start about the 200Gb?
And what should we do to get things set up correctly with no warning?

### commands used

*command 01 - create instance template

```
gcloud compute instance-templates create TEMPLATE-NAME
          --image='projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-1604-xenial-v20190212' \
          --custom-cpu=1 --custom-memory=2  \
          --boot-disk-size=200 --boot-disk-type=pd-standard
```

*command 02* - create compute instance from instance template

```
gcloud compute instances create INSTANCE_NAME \
          --source-instance-template TEMPLATE_NAME \
          --project=$GC_PROJECT --zone=$zone
```

Comment: It's a warning and you may ignore it at your discretion. To avoid the warning, revise your template to use disk size >= 200GB. Then, VMs created from the template will inherit the larger disk size too.

Comment: Ignore is of course what we did. The issue is the two warnings conflicts each other.

Comment: The messages don't conflict. I think you're not (as you think) setting the template boot disk size to 200GB *or* you're overriding this when you create the instance. Are you using Cloud Console or the command-line to do this?

Comment: `gcloud compute instance-templates create instance-template-1 --image=debian-9-drawfork-v20181101 --image-project=eip-images --boot-disk-size=200GB` then `gcloud compute instances create instance-1 --source-instance-template=instance-template-1 --zone=us-west1-c` then `gcloud compute disks describe instance-1 --zone=us-west1-c --format="value(sizeGb)"` returns `200` for me.

Comment: If you're using the Console and your template defines a container deployment, you may be experiencing an issue that I observed in which creating a VM from the template incorrectly overrides the template's boot disk size and defaults to 10GB. I've reported the bug.

Comment: It tells you exactly why it warns you. Decide whether it's relevant and then move on :)

Comment: @DazWilkin My question is taged by `command-line` and `gcloud` so yes, I'm using command-line gcloud

Comment: I'll add full command 01 create instance template, 02 create instance

Comment: Your commands similar to mine and I'm getting the conflicted warnings as described. No idea how you would get thru - maybe the image name differs.

Comment: Please remember that I'm trying to help you. Your sarcasm is unwarranted. I'll let you work this out for yourself. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help @DazWilkin. No idea why you say it in the way of such favor and not the stackoverflow manner dude. Thanks again.

Comment: @DazWilkin I just got this warning as well; I'm running a Docker container in my VM. You mentioned you submitted a bug report last year; did anything come of that?

Comment: @GaryO I was unable to find the issue. I've a feeling that I submitted the bug before I retired from Google; unfortunately, I now don't have access to those issues.